# Protected page using react-router-dom doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement only logged in user dashboard page.

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter history={hist}>
  <Route path="/sign-in" exact component={SignIn} />
  <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard">
    <Dashboard />
  </PrivateRoute>
</BrowserRouter>
```

PrivateRoute.js

```
export function PrivateRoute({children, ...props}) {
  return (
    <Route {...props} render={( {location} ) =>
      isAuthenticated ? children : <Redirect to="/sign-in" />
    }
    />
  );
}

const isAuthenticated = () => {
  const userToken = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user-token"));
  return userToken ? true : false'
}
```

I am checking sessionStorage for user-token, if it is null return false or true.
Event though it returns "false", it redirect to Dashboard, not Sign-in page.
What is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why router redirects to dashboard even not authenticated user is that `isAuthenticated` is a function. Since that, you need to call this function:

```
export function PrivateRoute({children, ...props}) {
  return (
    <Route {...props} render={( {location} ) =>
      isAuthenticated() ? children : <Redirect to="/sign-in" />
    }
    />
  );
}

const isAuthenticated = () => {
  const userToken = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user-token"));
  return userToken ? true : false'
}
```

If you don't want to invoke function each time route changes, you can implement an immediately invoked function:

```
const isAuthenticated = (() => {
  const userToken = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user-token"));
  return userToken ? true : false'
})()

export function PrivateRoute({children, ...props}) {
  return (
    <Route {...props} render={( {location} ) =>
      isAuthenticated ? children : <Redirect to="/sign-in" />
    }
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In PrivateRoute.js do this..

```
<Route {...props} render={( {location} ) =>
  isAuthenticated() ? children : <Redirect to="/sign-in" />
}
/>
```

The reason is that you are not calling the `isAuthenticated`. If the problem still persists, feel free to discuss.